# Scala, extending the iterator

Tags: scala, iterator, lazy-evaluation, extend, enrich-my-library

Im looking to extended the iterator to create a new method `takeWhileInclusive`, which will operate like `takeWhile` but include the last element.

My issue is what is best practice to extend the iterator to return a new iterator which I would like to be lazy evaluated.  Coming from a C# background I normal use `IEnumerable` and use the `yield` keyword, but such an option doesn't appear to exist in Scala.

for example I could have

```
List(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).iterator.map(complex time consuming algorithm).takeWhileInclusive(_ < 6)
```

so in this case the `takeWhileInclusive` would only have resolve the predicate on the values until I get the a result greater than 6, and it will include this first result

so far I have:

```
object ImplicitIterator {
  implicit def extendIterator(i : Iterator[Any]) = new IteratorExtension(i)
}

class IteratorExtension[T <: Any](i : Iterator[T]) {
  def takeWhileInclusive(predicate:(T) => Boolean) = ?
}
```

Comment: Did you have had a look at Stream?

Comment: A stream could definitely be more appropriate here in the example case, however I still have the same issue around how best to build the extension method

Comment: Oh, `takeWhileInclusive`. My old [`takeTo`](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2963)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one case where I find the mutable solution superior:

```
class InclusiveIterator[A](ia: Iterator[A]) {
  def takeWhileInclusive(p: A => Boolean) = {
    var done = false
    val p2 = (a: A) => !done && { if (!p(a)) done=true; true }
    ia.takeWhile(p2)
  }
}
implicit def iterator_can_include[A](ia: Iterator[A]) = new InclusiveIterator(ia)
```

Comment: This is definitely an elegant solution to my problem, cheers!

Comment: I'll take the functional version with neither `var`s nor `val`s, thanks!

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - If you don't mind the extra overhead, that's a fine alternative.  (Normally I wouldn't use a val for the function; I was just trying to separate things out for clarity here.)

Comment: It was more the `var` I objected to! And I wasn't being particularly serious anyway

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `span` method of `Iterator` to do this pretty cleanly:

```
class IteratorExtension[A](i : Iterator[A]) {
  def takeWhileInclusive(p: A => Boolean) = {
    val (a, b) = i.span(p)
    a ++ (if (b.hasNext) Some(b.next) else None)
  }
}

object ImplicitIterator {
  implicit def extendIterator[A](i : Iterator[A]) = new IteratorExtension(i)
}

import ImplicitIterator._
```

Now `(0 until 10).toIterator.takeWhileInclusive(_ < 4).toList` gives `List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)`, for example.

Comment: Your method's last line can be written more succinctly as `a ++ (b take 1)`

Answer (score 3):

The following requires scalaz to get `fold` on a tuple `(A, B)`

```
scala> implicit def Iterator_Is_TWI[A](itr: Iterator[A]) = new { 
     | def takeWhileIncl(p: A => Boolean) 
     |   = itr span p fold (_ ++ _.toStream.headOption)
     | }
Iterator_Is_TWI: [A](itr: Iterator[A])java.lang.Object{def takeWhileIncl(p: A => Boolean): Iterator[A]}
```

Here it is at work:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).iterator takeWhileIncl (_ < 4)
res0: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0.toList
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

You can roll your own fold over a pair like this:

```
scala> implicit def Pair_Is_Foldable[A, B](pair: (A, B)) = new { 
    |    def fold[C](f: (A, B) => C): C = f.tupled(pair) 
    |  } 
Pair_Is_Foldable: [A, B](pair: (A, B))java.lang.Object{def fold[C](f: (A, B) => C): C}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class IteratorExtension[T](i : Iterator[T]) {
  def takeWhileInclusive(predicate:(T) => Boolean) = new Iterator[T] {
    val it = i
    var isLastRead = false

    def hasNext = it.hasNext && !isLastRead
    def next = {
      val res = it.next
      isLastRead = !predicate(res)
      res
    }
  }
}
```

And there's an error in your implicit. Here it is fixed:

```
object ImplicitIterator {
  implicit def extendIterator[T](i : Iterator[T]) = new IteratorExtension(i)
}
```

Comment: This was where my thinking was heading, thank you for getting there for me! It does offer a good generalised approach.  I wish there was a more elegant general solution then having to construct a new iterator.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> List(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).toStream.filter (_ < 6).take(2)
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res8.toList 
res9: List[Int] = List(0, 1)
```

After your update:

```
scala> def timeConsumeDummy (n: Int): Int = {
     | println ("Time flies like an arrow ...") 
     | n }
timeConsumeDummy: (n: Int)Int

scala> List(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7).toStream.filter (x => timeConsumeDummy (x) < 6) 
Time flies like an arrow ...
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res14.take (4).toList 
Time flies like an arrow ...
Time flies like an arrow ...
Time flies like an arrow ...
res15: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

timeConsumeDummy is called 4 times. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry the example isn't the specific case I'm looking to solve, I will include a more in-depth example to illustrate what I am after

Comment: @JPullar: Your take (2) has vanished and changed place with (_ < 6), while the timeConsumingMethod is on the left of (_ < 6) now. So does (timeConsumingMethod) produce an Int as result, which is compared to (_ < 6) now, or is it the initial List element, which has to be below 6?

Comment: What your showing is correct and what I am after in the lazy evaluation.  My issue however, is to emulate how the filter function is evaluating lazily in a custom extension method

Comment: So if `timeConsumeDummy` returns `2*n - 1`, all computations get performed, that's true.